# Crash, when change rootController with animation

Tags: ios, animation, uistackview

I using this function for changing actual app root controller:

```
class func setRootController(newController: UIViewController, animation: UIViewAnimationOptions? = nil) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    if animation != nil {

        let currentController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController!

        UIView.transition(from: currentController.view, to: newController.view, duration: 0.6, options: animation!, completion: { (completed) in
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = newController
        })


    } else {
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = newController
    }
}
```

My controller willAppear (called twice when using setRoot: 1 - when controller created and animation begin, 2 - in completion block):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    balanceView.bonuses = bonuses
}
```

My balanceView (just a UIView) contains bonusesStack (stackView) and var bonuses with didSet:

```
var bonuses: [Bonus]! {
    didSet {

        for subview in bonusesStack.arrangedSubviews {
            bonusesStack.removeArrangedSubview(subview)
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        bonuses.forEach { (bonus) in
            let bonusView = BonusBalanceView.loadFromXib(bonus: bonus)

            bonusesStack.addArrangedSubview(bonusView)
        }
    }
}

class func loadFromXib(bonus: Bonus) -> BonusBalanceView {
    let bonusView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: BonusBalanceView.self), owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! BonusBalanceView
    // some code here
    return bonusView
}
```

When willAppear called second time, code crashes at line `subview.removeFromSuperview()` (bcs at second time, superview is nil. I try to add if block for superview checking, but for some reasons it executing always O_o)

If I comment/remove this line (which is not recommended, bcs view still in stackView subview), code crashes in completion block

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my custom View. I overrided draw method and work with layers programmatically. In xib file, this view contain subview. Somehow   ( ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ) this layers and subview conflict and crash app